# TTS has stopped working in Apple Books

Tags: macos, books

Before Monterey, I could use the Text-to-speech feature in Books.app. It stopped working for me and I miss it so much. I have tried other e-book readers (Calibre, some garbage from Adobe) where the TTS feature works but I don't like using for various nit-picky reasons.

So how to make TTS work again in Books.app?

Comment: A good question should be about one thing - see the FAQ for more info. So in this case please remove the last line - that is an open ended question asking for opinions as well as getting different answers to the rest of the question,